# how to terminate thread if not finished in N seconds after I joined it?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm using such pattern:

```
boost::thread receiverThread;
....
stayConnected = false;
if (receiverThread.joinable()) {
    receiverThread.join();
}
```

`receiverThread` thread periodically checks `stayConnected` flag and when it set to `false` it should terminate.

Now I want to protect main code from "bad" `receiverThread`, if `receiverThread` not finished after 5 seconds i want to kill it:

```
boost::thread receiverThread;
....
stayConnected = false;
if (receiverThread.joinable()) {
    receiverThread.join();
    // not to hang forever, if receiverThread not finished after 5 seconds, kill it
}
```

what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Boost doesn't provide any thread [cancellation/termination](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/doc/html/thread/faq.html#id1746521):

> #### 9. Why isn't thread cancellation or termination provided?
>
> There's a valid need for thread termination, so at some point `Boost.Thread` probably will include it, but only after we can find a truly safe (and portable) mechanism for this concept.

However, it's better to check the `stayConnected` at some safe-points. If you have to much time passing between those points, try to find a new safe-point in-between.

Comment: thanks, i think probably i will just use `try_join_for`, i'm looking for example.